# I'm facing problem to create a trigger that will update the status of a parents custom object (training__c) to chlid custom object(book__c)

Tags: apex, trigger

[image][image]

```
 trigger Train on Training__c ( after insert,after update){
      Set<id> StatusActive= new Set<Id>();
      Set<id> StatusInActive= new Set<Id>(); 

       for (Training__c t1: Trigger.new){
               if (t1.status__c !='Inactive') {
               StatusActive.add(t1.whatId);
            }
            else if (t1.status__c =='Inactive')
             {
            StatusInActive.add(t1.whatId);
            }
        }
      
      
        if (StatusActive > 0){
                List<Book__c> Booksobject = [Select id, status__c from book__c where id =: StatusActive];
                for(Book__c thisObject: Booksobject)
                 {
                    thisObject.status__c='Active';
                 }
            update Booksobject;
            }
    
        if (StatusInActive.size() > 0) 
        {
            List<Book__c> Booksobject= [Select id, status__c from book__c where id =: StatusInActive];
            for(Book__c thisObject: Booksobject){
            thisObject.status__c='Inactive';
        }
        update Booksobject;
    } 
    }
```

---

this is what im facing the problem

```
trigger book1 on Book__c( after insert,after update)
{
 List<Training__c> childRecords = [Select Book__c, Status__c FROM Training__c WHERE Book__c IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    for(Training__c child :childRecords)
    {

     if(trigger.isInsert && child.Status__c == 'Active')
       {
         child.status__c = 'Active';
       }
       else
         if(trigger.isUpdate && child.Status__c == 'inactive' && trigger.NewMap.get(child.Book__c).Status__c != trigger.OldMap.get(child.Book__c).Status__c)
        {

            child.status__c = 'active';
         }
     }
        if(childRecords.size() > 0)
        //update childRecords;
        {
//System.debug('Chris has values to insert = '+ newConList.size());
try
     {
    update childRecords;
     }
     catch (System.Dmlexception e)  
     {
     system.debug (e); 
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you copy your error?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: whatId at line 9 column 36

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error and also the field **WhatId** in the Training__c object?

Comment: Also, show the fields of Training__c object.

Comment: @Ankita I Added the sreen shot of training....

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There seems error in your code. Both If block are checking for the 'Inactive' status. I have corrected that code.

```
     if (t1.status__c !='Active') {               
 StatusActive.add(t1.whatId);             
} else if (t1.status__c =='Inactive')         
     {         
    StatusInActive.add(t1.whatId);   
          }
```

Regrading your compiler error, WhatId is not a column on your Training__c object. Can you check Training__c object and verify if you are using the correct column. Since It's a custom column It should have ended with a __c. Just use the correct column name, you should be good to go then.

Comment: no bhawna its not my solution..... which id i set right that id is not taking in that what id

Comment: Ok Here is  my understanding.                                                                                   You basically want to update the Book Object as Active or inactive depending upon if the status of Parent Training object is 'Active' or 'Inactive' . You need to fetch the Book object Ids associated with a training object instead of this WhatId.                                                                       Replace the lines    StatusActive.add(t1.whatId);   StatusInActive.add(t1.whatId);   with          StatusActive.add(t1.book__r.Id);       StatusInActive.add(t1.book__r.Id);

Answer (score 0):

WhatId field is not in the Training__c object. Use Book__c to resolve the issue.

```
trigger Train on Training__c ( after insert,after update){
      Set<id> StatusActive= new Set<Id>();
      Set<id> StatusInActive= new Set<Id>(); 

       for (Training__c t1: Trigger.new){
               if (t1.status__c !='Inactive') {
               StatusActive.add(t1.Book__c);
            }
            else if (t1.status__c =='Inactive')
             {
            StatusInActive.add(t1.Book__c);
            }
        }
      
      
        if (StatusActive > 0){
                List<Book__c> Booksobject = [Select id, status__c from book__c where id IN: StatusActive];
                for(Book__c thisObject: Booksobject)
                 {
                    thisObject.status__c='Active';
                 }
            update Booksobject;
            }
    
        if (StatusInActive.size() > 0) 
        {
            List<Book__c> Booksobject= [Select id, status__c from book__c where id IN: StatusInActive];
            for(Book__c thisObject: Booksobject){
            thisObject.status__c='Inactive';
        }
        update Booksobject;
    } 
    }
```

Comment: This really isn't much of an answer. You may have identified the solution to one part of the issue, but you haven't provided any indication of where it should be used, or how it solves the issue at hand. I've downvoted this answer.

Comment: @DerekF - I have updated the answer.

Comment: Retracted my downvote